# Correct way to bundle in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a bit confused on the correct way to bundle script and style files.  Currently, my BundleConfig.cs looks like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

// Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
// ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
            "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.debug.js",
            "~/Scripts/knockout-sortable.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/BootStrapcss").Include(
            "~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.css",
            "~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap-fileupload.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/BootStrap").Include(
            "~/BootStrap/tpg-main.css",
            "~/BootStrap/tpg-internal.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/BootStrapjs").Include(
            "~/BootStrap/js/bootstrap-fileupload.js",
            "~/BootStrap/js/bootstrap.js"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Should stay with what I have, or bundle all my script files into one `ScriptBundle`, and all my styles into one `StyleBundle`? I want to achieve the best performance possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are always using all of the files than go ahead and stick them in two bundles; one for the javascript and one for the styles.  Fewer bundles means fewer requests to the server to fetch the resources, which may result in marginally better performance on the first hit; subsequently the files will be cached by the browser.

If you are not always using all of the files than it makes more sense to break them out into more bundles.

Comment: To clarify his point, you may only need to use Knockout on one or two pages for example, and not your entire site.  Therefore, you shouldn't bundle it together with everything else because it will be loaded on pages where it's not used or needed.

Comment: @Moozhe Yes thank you, I should have expanded on that a little more for completeness.

Comment: How to bundle jquery, validate and modernizr into one?

Comment: what about bundling the site.css. If there are changes to the file, do browsers know to clear the cache and re-fetch?

Comment: @ganders From [ASP.NET MVC Bundling and Minification Page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) in the **Bundle Caching** section, _"If any file in the bundle changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework will generate a new token, guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the latest bundle."_.

Comment: @tastro Just put them in a bundle by themselves?
    `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mybundle").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));`

Comment: When creating a new project in Visual Studio 2017, by default in _Layout.cshtml it creates a link to get bootstrap from a cloud server with asp-fallback to get it on our server if that fails. So which one is the right way? That approach of getting it from the cloud with fallback to our server is probably slightly more performant -- and then where to get the right syntax to add other common scripts?